# Need easy to use numbered list software

Tags: windows

I use Evernote but changing order of items in big lists using drag and drop turns into a pain on more than 20 points also it doesn't support folding of items

MS Word is a horrible to use - hard to format and no items folding

MS Excel seems to be the closesest to the idea but  istoo complicated.

The Windows compatibility is preferable but a web software fine too